# How to add values to a key in python using a .json file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I am using .JSON files and the JSON Library to store information when it is passed in through discord. I'm storing the values like this:

```
{
    "key": {
        "value1": "value2"
    }
}
```

Whenever I pass in some new values in the same key, instead of adding the values below or above the current values, the values just change to the newest value.

What I want to have happen:

```
{
    "key": {
        "value1": "value2"
        "value3": "value4"
    }
}
```

What actually happens:

```
{
    "key": {
        "value3": "value4"
    }
}
```

Here is my code:

```
@commands.command()
    async def add_reaction_role(self, ctx, message_id, reaction, role):
        with open("data.json") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        data[message_id] = {}
        # add keys to message_id like this
        data[message_id] = {reaction: role}
        # it will be like {"message_id": {"key1": {"another_key": "something"}}}

        with open('data.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=4)  # indent for nice visualization
```

Anything would be helpfull, ask me if you need clarification on anything.
Thanks!

Comment: thats is actually what I had at first but it still just updates the values

Comment: You can use update of dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is each time you are assigning a new dict so it will replaces the old value with current value and don't do this `data[message_id] = {}` instead use `dict.setdefault()`

```
with open("data.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data.setdefault(message_id, {})
data[message_id][reaction] = role
```

Answer (score 1):

comments are correct. just like to elaborate so you understand the issue here -

looks like what you want is:

```
{
    "key": {                 // message_id
        "value1": "value2"   // recation: role
        "value3": "value4"   // reaction: role
    }
}
```

but what you do is replacing all of the inner dict, instead of adding values.

```
{
    "key": **{
        "value1": "value2"   
        "value3": "value4"   
    }**
}
```

(when you do this: `data[message_id] = {}`)